# Open elements in a topology

Tags: general-topology

Is it true to say that an element of an element in a topology is open in a topological space?

To try and be more clear, if I have a topological space $X=\{a,b,c\}$ with topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, X, \{a,b\}\}$, is it true that $b$ is open in the space? Does this question even make sense?

Comment: What's the definition of a topology?

Comment: The elements of $\tau$ are open subsets of the space. I'm in a jam over what this means for elements within each subset. I'm inclined to say that, since $b$ on its own isn't an element of $\tau$, $b$ is not open... I'm in a tangle

Comment: It doesn't mean anything for the elements of a set in the topology. A set (subset of $X$, in this context) is open (if it's in $\tau$) or not (if it's not in $\tau$). It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it make sense? Not really - the topology defines the open subsets of $X$, and the element $b \in X$ is not a subset of $X$ (certainly not in general; I don't recall whether axiomatic set theory allows $b \in X \wedge b \subset X$).

However, $\{b\} \subset X$, but $\{b\} \notin \tau$, so it isn't open.

Comment: You *can* have $b \in X$ and $b \subset X$ as well. E.g. for ordinals.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, you are right - thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\{b\}$ is not open as it is not a member of $\tau$. Your description of the topology is just an exhaustive list of *all* open sets. Not in the list = not open.

Answer (score 1):

The only open sets that you can form are given by intersection and union of elements of $\tau$, so $\{ b \}$ is not open.

As a side note, there exist topologies such that every point forms an open set. Indeed, consider an arbitrary set $X$ and define $\tau_X$ to be its power set. It is not hard to see that $\tau_X$ is a topology and $\{ x \}$ is open for all $x \in X$. This is called the *discrete topology*.